# How do you convert this formula to conjunctive normal form? $(b\land c) \leftrightarrow (((-a \lor c) \rightarrow -b) \lor a ))$

Tags: logic

I understand that this has been gone over before, but every method I've found leads me to the wrong answer for this particular logical statement. I would appreciate if someone could give me some help:

$$(b\land c) \leftrightarrow (((-a \lor c) \rightarrow -b) \lor a ))$$

I'm not exaggerating when I say I've been at this problem for 2 hours. I eliminate the equivalence, then the implications, then distribute the negations, and then use distributivity, but I always end up with the wrong answer.

Comment: What answer do you get?

Comment: @saulspatz Ever since I've started using the method, I get something like $(-b \lor -c \lor a) \land ((-a \land b) \lor (b \land c))$.

Comment: Which I know to be wrong because I've done the truth table of the original expression. On top of that, it's not even in CNF anyhow.

Comment: You should show your work.  You'll find lots of people here who are willing to check your work (not me -- I'm going to bed) but nowhere near as many who are willing to the problem from scratch for you.

Comment: You're right. I'll do that now, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, you are starting with $(b\land c)\leftrightarrow(((\lnot a\lor c)\to\lnot b)\lor a))$ and aiming for a conjunctive series of disjunctive series of literals and negations of literals; that is a CNF.

It might be tempting to begin with biconditional equivalence, but it may be better to first tidy up the RHS.   It avoids confusion and prevents doubling up your workload to do it now.   So your very first step will be to use conditional equivalence $p\to q\iff \lnot p\lor q$

$$(b\land c)\leftrightarrow((\lnot(\lnot a\lor c)\lor\lnot b)\lor a)$$

So, obviously you will want to apply de Morgan's Law, then use association and commutation, and so forth, until the RHS is nice and tidy.

Then you can apply a biconditional equivalence; use $(p\leftrightarrow q)\iff((p\lor\lnot q)\land(\lnot p\lor q))$, since you want a CNF.

Use de Morgan's Law again, and then all that will be left for you to do will be some distribution.

Good luck.